# Get position of list-item in an unordered list (ie. 3rd list item is 3)

Tags: javascript, position, listitem

I have an unordered list, with a couple list-items inside. Inside each of those is a link. What I want to do is find the position of the list-item when someone clicks the link inside it.

For example, if someone clicks the link inside the 3rd list-item, it gives me a value of 3.

I already have the click part, just need to figure out how to get the position of the list-item

Javascript only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple live example that does what you want (except the list does not have links)

http://jsfiddle.net/8k926/2/

In the "Result" box click on one of the list items.  It will have a handler that pops up its sequence number.

The Javascript code is the following

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(els,function(el,i){
    el.addEventListener('click', function(){alert(i);}, false);
  }) ;
```

Although `els` is array-like, it does not have a `forEach` method.  We get around that by using the `Array.prototype.forEach` method.

**Update:** Here's a second live example that narrows things down to a specific list, as opposed to all list items.

http://jsfiddle.net/8k926/3/

Also, as a commenter points out, `forEach` is not universally supported, but it is used here to simplify the code.

Comment: You should test for `Array.prototype.forEach` first, it is not implemented everywhere.

Comment: @RobG, that was in the back of my mind, but ignoring it for simplicity  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: This works really well. But that takes into account all list-items on the page. Can I narrow it down to a specific unordered list?

Comment: What would you do if you didnt want it to count nested unordered lists?

Comment: @brainjam Great! Thanks for very helpful example code + explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
// A ul only has li childnodes.

count 'backwards' from the  li element containing the clicked link.


var count= 1, li= linkelement;
while(li && li.nodeName!= 'LI') li= li.parentNode; // get the li element
while(li){
    li= li.previousSibling;
    // count previous li elements
    ++count;
}
alert(count)// firstChild is 1, not 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery: add a click event to all links in lists which firstly selects the parent 'li' element of the link, then walks backwards selecting each 'li' element until there are no more to select and an empty jquery object is returned. Should be easy to adapt.

```
$('li a').click(function(){
    $node = $(this).parent();
    result = 0;
    while ($node.length > 0){
        result++;
        $node = $node.prev();
    }
    alert(result);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have stated I needed javascript only. I'll adjust my post.

Comment: @Noah, it is only javascript! Not to worry...brainjam's answer is cleverer anyway...